# No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement - error php MySQLi

Tags: php, html

i'm very new to php. So, I tried to make a simple form to order sandwiches, but when I click the submit button i get this error "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement".

Btw, I copied most of the code from a YouTube video, and I don't know what some parts of the code actually do.

that's my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) &&
        isset($_POST['bocadillo']) && isset($_POST['extra']) &&
        isset($_POST['comentario']) && isset($_POST['comentario'])) {
        
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $bocadillo = $_POST['bocadillo'];
        $extra = $_POST['extra'];
        $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

        $host = "localhost";
        $dbUsername = "------";
        $dbpassword = "------";
        $dbName = "------";

        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbpassword, $dbName);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Could not connect to the database.');
        }
        else {
            $Select = "SELECT extra FROM pedidos WHERE extra = ? LIMIT 1";
            $Insert = "INSERT INTO pedidos(nombre, apellido, bocadillo, extra, comentario) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($Select);

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($resultemail);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->fetch();
            $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

            if ($rnum == 0) {
                $stmt->close();

                $stmt = $conn->prepare($Insert);

                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    echo "New record inserted sucessfully.";
                }
                else {
                    echo $stmt->error;
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "Someone already registers using this email.";
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "All field are required.";
        die();
    }
}
else {
    echo "Submit button is not set";
}
?>
```

Comment: The only thing you're doing with e.g. `$_POST['nombre']` is copying it to `$nombre`. PHP has no way to know you want it injected in the first `?` placeholder at `$stmt = $conn->prepare($Insert)`. Don't try to guess how mysqli works because it's isn't particularly intuitive, just look at the examples in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `bind_param` statements for both queries

```
$Select = "SELECT extra FROM pedidos WHERE extra = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Select);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $extra);
$stmt->execute();
```

and then in the insert

```
$Insert = "INSERT INTO pedidos(nombre, apellido, bocadillo, extra, comentario) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Select);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $nombre, $apellido, $bocadillo, $extra, $comentario);
$stmt->execute();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp